# MusiXTex Error: "Emergency Stop.<read 1> \startpiece"

Tags: errors, compilation-error, musixtex

I am currently trying to use MusiXTeX for typesetting music notes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a5paper, twoside, left=1.5cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\input musixtex
\input musixper.tex
\input musixlit.tex
\input musixadd.tex
\input musixbm.tex
\input musixgui.tex
\input musixlyr%

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
     \startpiece%
      \setemptybar%
     \endpiece%
\end{music}

Test. Test. Test.

\begin{music}
\setclefsymbol6
\changecontext%
\setclef16%
\setstaffs1{1}%
\setlyrics{v1}{ut que -ant la -sis, re -so -na -re fi -bris, Mi__-ra ges -to_-rum, Fa -mu -li tu_-orum}%
\assignlyrics{1}{v1}%
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\startpiece%
\NOtes \addspace\afterruleskip \wh{c d f} \beginmel \wh{d}\endmel \wh{e d} \en\bar%
\NOtes \addspace\afterruleskip \caesura \wh{ddc} \wh{d e e} \en\bar%
\NOtes \addspace\afterruleskip \caesura \beginmel \wh{e f} \endmel \wh{g e d e c d} \en%
\endpiece%
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

There was no problem, when I compiled this code (besides the notes in the second staff). But if I execute MusixFLX and compile again, I get an error message saying "Emergency stop. \startpiece". I suspect it has something to do with my approch to create an empty staff, because if I delete

```
\begin{music}
     \startpiece%
      \setemptybar%
     \endpiece%
\end{music}
```

everything works perfectly fine. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this (of course without deleting the empty staff)?

Answer (score 1):

I think `\setemptybar` means to set the next bar line invisible, so if you want to use it you need input at least an empty notes, e.g. `\notes\en`.

This is an empty staff

```
\begin{music}
\startpiece%
\notes\en
\endpiece%
\end{music}
```

This is an empty staff without ending bar

```
\begin{music}
\startpiece%
\notes\en\setemptybar%
\endpiece%
\end{music}
```

[image: Example figure]